# Uploading Captions using YouTube API v3 (dotnet, C#, Null Error, CHALLENGING)

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, youtube-data-api, captions

I'm trying to upload closed captions using oauth2 with the youtube dotnet libraries. The samples don't include .NET and I understand this is new (i.e. lightly used functionality in the API). I'm pulling my hair out on this one and don't know if I'm missing something or if there could be a bug in the API. Please Help!

The error I get is:

    `BytesSent: 0
    Exception: {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: baseUri"}
    Status: Failed`

My code WORKS for uploading a VIDEO but gives the error above when uploading a CAPTION.

Here is the code which includes both working VIDEO UPLOAD and broken CAPTION UPLOAD.

```
// THIS ONE WORKS !!!!
        private void cmdUploadVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        YouTubeService youtubeService = getYouTubeService();

        Video newVideo = new Video();
        newVideo.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        newVideo.Snippet.Title = "Learning YouTube API 2";
        newVideo.Snippet.Description = "Description of video";
        newVideo.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
        newVideo.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
        newVideo.Status = new VideoStatus();
        newVideo.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
        var filePath = @"c:\\_IM\\TestVideo.mp4"; 

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            VideosResource.InsertMediaUpload videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(newVideo, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
            IUploadProgress results = videosInsertRequest.Upload();
        }
    }

// HELP PLEASE!!! VERY SIMILAR STRUCTURE BUT GETS ERROR
    private void cmdUploadVideoCaption_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        YouTubeService youtubeService = getYouTubeService();

        Caption newCaption = new Caption();
        newCaption.Snippet = new CaptionSnippet();
        newCaption.Snippet.Name = "test";
        newCaption.Snippet.Language = "en";
        newCaption.Snippet.VideoId = txtVideoID.Text;
        var filePath = @"c:\\_IM\\captions.txt"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            CaptionsResource.InsertMediaUpload captionInsertRequest = youtubeService.Captions.Insert(newCaption, "snippet,status", fileStream, "*/*");
            captionInsertRequest.Sync = true;
            IUploadProgress result = captionInsertRequest.Upload();
// HELP WITH LINE ABOVE ... THAT IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        }
    }

// THIS PART WORKS !!!! IT IS USED BY BOTH, OAUTH2
    private YouTubeService getYouTubeService()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;
        }

        YouTubeService youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });

        return youtubeService;
    }
```

Here is the error output from the code above:

```
?result
{Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload<Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Caption>.ResumableUploadProgress}
    [Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload<Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Caption>.ResumableUploadProgress]: {Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload<Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Caption>.ResumableUploadProgress}
    BytesSent: 0
    Exception: {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: baseUri"}
    Status: Failed

?result.Exception
{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: baseUri"}
    [System.ArgumentNullException]: {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: baseUri"}
    _className: null
    _data: null
    _dynamicMethods: null
    _exceptionMethod: null
    _exceptionMethodString: null
    _helpURL: null
    _HResult: -2147467261
    _innerException: null
    _ipForWatsonBuckets: 1903238454
    _message: "Value cannot be null."
    _remoteStackIndex: 0
    _remoteStackTraceString: null
    _safeSerializationManager: {System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager}
    _source: null
    _stackTrace: {sbyte[96]}
    _stackTraceString: null
    _watsonBuckets: null
    _xcode: -532462766
    _xptrs: 0
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    HResult: -2147467261
    InnerException: null
    IPForWatsonBuckets: 1903238454
    IsTransient: false
    Message: "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: baseUri"
    RemoteStackTrace: null
    Source: "Microsoft.Threading.Tasks"
    StackTrace: "   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.<UploadCoreAsync>d__e.MoveNext() in c:\\code\\github\\google-api-dotnet-client\\Tools\\Google.Apis.Release\\bin\\Release\\1.9.2\\default\\Src\\GoogleApis\\Apis\\[Media]\\Upload\\ResumableUpload.cs:line 460"
    TargetSite: {Void ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)}
    WatsonBuckets: null
```

Note, I tried doing this as an async task and get the same error but maybe the output will be more informative for debugging since it includes line numbers in ResumableUpload. Here is the error output when making the async call (code not shown):

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in System.Net.Http.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll
An error prevented the upload from completing.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.<UploadAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\code\github\google-api-dotnet-client\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Release\1.9.2\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:line 378
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll
An error prevented the upload from completing.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: baseUri
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.<UploadCoreAsync>d__e.MoveNext() in c:\code\github\google-api-dotnet-client\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Release\1.9.2\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:line 460
```

BTW, I updated my nuget youtube libraries on the evening of Aug 03, 2015 so I'm using the latest code available to me.

Thank you to anyone who can help!!!!

Comment: Good question. I could resolve my question based on yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code helped me solve a separate issue I was having with the same task.  As for your error, I think it comes from the

```
"snippet/status"
```

parameter in the Insert() method.  It seems that the API expects both a snippet and status object (which you are passing with your cmdUploadVideo_Click()
method.  The following code works for me...

```
    YouTubeService youtubeService = GetYouTubeService();

    Caption caption = new Caption();
    caption.Snippet = new CaptionSnippet();
    caption.Snippet.Name = "Test Caption";
    caption.Snippet.Language = "en";
    caption.Snippet.VideoId = "videoId";
    caption.Snippet.IsDraft = false;

    var filePath = "{filepath}";
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        CaptionsResource.InsertMediaUpload captionInsertRequest = youtubeService.Captions.Insert(caption, "snippet", fileStream, "*/*");
        captionInsertRequest.Sync = true;
        captionInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += captionInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
        captionInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += captionInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
        IUploadProgress result = captionInsertRequest.Upload();
    }
```

Hope this helps.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @mpwhitt mentioned.  Be sure your caption file (@"c:\_IM\captions.txt") is correct.  Just to be sure will you use an example caption file or this code that creates one:

```
File.WriteAllText( "example.srt",
@"1
00:00:00.00 --> 00:00:03.00
This is just an example

2
00:00:03.00 --> 00:00:07.00
and we'll see if it works
" );
```

I see you set the scope that you need (YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl) according to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/insert)  In my usage I used the other one (YouTubePartner); but either should work according to documentation.

I set captionInsertRequest.Sync to false.  I think with it set to true it'll need to process.  But nonetheless it shouldn't error out with it set as true.  But with it to false it should both succeed and show up right away in your video.